# Magento add to cart via GET

Tags: module, cart, magento2.3.4

I have the following problem:

I need to add products into the cart with for example:

```
http://host.com/checkout/cart/add?product=2&qty=5
```

I have tried to create a module to "catch" the GET request and to proceed some process and then to redirect the user to the checkout page

I have tried this solution:

[Passing the Product id and form key but not adding to cart in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268218/passing-the-product-id-and-form-key-but-not-adding-to-cart-in-magento2)

But it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to make this work?
My Module Structure is `Gep/Cartadd`

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.9.3 you can try something like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>
```

It will give you an add url with form key, which you don't have. Then you can add for example:

```
?super_attribute[150]=177&qty=1
```

Comment: we upgrade to magento 2.3.4

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153217/magento-2-how-to-get-add-to-cart-url-in-custom-templete-file-and-add-product-to  did you try this ?